# refresing Oracle MV remotely

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to refresh Oracle Materialized View on remote DB using DB Link name. everything working fine once I'm using static db link name like

```
DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH@QA_LINK('tablename_mv','?')
```

BUT

when I want to get it (db link name) as a variable  in many ways

```
v_dblink :='qa';
DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH@v_dblink('AVBROCHURESTATS','?');
```

always getting an errors like

```
ORA-06550: line 57, column 15:
PLS-00352: Unable to access another database 'V_DBLINK'
ORA-06550: line 57, column 15:
PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_MVIEW@V_DBLINK' must be declared.
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

DB link names must always be explicit; there's no variable substitution in the DDL. The best you could do would be to use dynamic SQL to build the execution string on the fly:

```
v_dblink := 'QA'
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH@' || v_dblink ||'(''AVBROCHURESTATS'',''?'')';
```

Comment: as I wrote I did that using few ways. One was created fuction. I was try to hardcoding it but the result is ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement . In your propesed cases I've got an error like "SP2-0552: Bind variable "V_DBLINK" not declared.

Comment: Sorry - i shouldn't have made that a bind variable. Try without the ":". If you'd like a more detailed analysis of your other previous attempts, please post the code you tried in your question.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was related to the same invoking , becuse
with execute immediate you need to put that statement into a begin end; block
like

```
execute immediate ' begin DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH@'|| v_dblink||'(''AVBROCHURESTATS'',''?''); end;';
```